# What happens if pass extra variables in ExpressJS middleware?

Tags: node.js, express

Some libraries declare own custom middleware function like this

```
function ApiCache() {

   ...
   return makeResponseCacheable(req, res, next, key, duration, strDuration, middlewareToggle)
}
```

that pass extra variables, not like the standard middleware's signature is `function(req, res, next)` only get three variables?

Answer (score 0):

you can pass any no. of argument in express internally it is like a var arg function which checks all the middleware's passed

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments the way you want. But i would suggest to create the middleware function and use that in middleware.

The **ES6** pattern make it simple,

```
    let _listener: express.Express;
    const myMiddlewareClass: MyMiddlewareClass= new AuthorMyMiddlewareClassizationMiddleware(arg1, arg2, arg3);
    _listener.use(route, myMiddlewareClass.makeResponseCacheable.bind(myMiddlewareClass));
```

Here, using **bind** will make the variables accessible outside the class or function directly.